# Como importar paquetes locales en go?

Tags: go

Soy nuevo en golang y necesito entender como GO implementa los paquetes en general. Quiero implementar un paquete local para separar mi código y mantenerlo ordenado.

Tengo el siguiente ejemplo:

**nums.go**

```
package nums

func Even(i int) bool {
  return i % 2 == 0
}

func Odd(i int) bool {
  return i % 2 == 1
}
```

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
  "./nums"
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  a := 5
  b := 6

  fmt.Printf("%d is even %v?\n", a, nums.Even(a))
  fmt.Printf("%d is odd %v?\n", b, nums.Odd(b))
}
```

Al intentar correr el comando `go run main.go` me lanza el siguiente error:

> main.go:4:5: open /home/ubuntu/workspace/nums: no such file or directory

¿A qué se debe esto? ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que tu paquete "**nums**" no existe. La estructura de carpetas deberia ser la siguiente :

```
project/
 nums/
    nums.go
    another-package.go
 main.go
```

Para entender mejor golang, te recomiendo leer el tutorial oficial:  [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).

Comment: gracias Andy, efectivamente colocándole en una carpeta con el mismo nombre funcionó. Me toca investigar más :)

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas el orden de tus carpetas correctamente como lo especifica el [tutorial de go sobre como escribir código go](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) puedes importarlos de la siguiente manera:

```
"github.com/tu_usuario_de_github/nombre_del_paquete"
```

Los paquetes que desarrolles se pueden integrar con github, por eso se necesita la carpeta de tu nombre de usuario de github también puedes descargar paquetes que desarrollan otras personas.